# How to write a destructurable object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to write a class in Kotlin so that it could be destructured upon initialization, like:

```
val (set, list, map) = CollectionsGenerator(arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to destructure an object, you need to define methods on it that are of the following form (where `X` is a number starting at 1 and the return type can be whatever you wish to return):

```
operator fun componentX(): Any {}
```

To do something similar to what's in your question, you could save the parameters you've constructed the class with to properties, and then the `component` methods can use those properties:

```
class SetAndListMaker(val i: Int, val s: String) {

    operator fun component1() = setOf(i, s)

    operator fun component2() = listOf(i, s)

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val (set, list) = SetAndListMaker(25, "dog")
}
```

This main function is no different from this one, of course:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val setAndListMaker = SetAndListMaker(25, "dog")
    val (set, list) = setAndListMaker
}
```

[And here's the official documentation about destructuring declarations.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html)